# Maximum number of items in a J2ME List

Tags: java, list, java-me, lcdui

I'm working on j2me project that involves getting a list of users from an online database, I then intend to populate a list with the names of the users and the number can be very large. my question is - are there limits to the number of items you can append to a list?

```
    HttpConnection hc = (HttpConnection);
    String reply;
    Connector.open("http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/......?xx=xx");
    InputStream is = new hc.openInputStream();
  int ch;
      // Check the Content-Length first
          long len = hc.getLength();
         if(len!=-1) {
        for(int i = 0;i&lt;len;i++)
         if((ch = is.read())!= -1)
          reply += (char) ch;
      } else {
        // if the content-length is not available
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
          reply += (char) ch;
      }
    is.close();
    hc.close();
    DataParser parser = new DataParser(reply); // This is a custom class I created to process the XML data returned from the server to split it into groups and put in an array.
    List user list = new List("Users");
    if (parser.moveToNext()) {
    do {
    list.append(parser.get(), null);
    }
    }
```

This code seems to be working fine but my problem is, if a keep calling list.append("", null), will it get to a point when some exception is thrown, maybe in the case of 50,000 names (list items)?

Comment: could you care to share what you have started with i mean the actual implementation rather than the concept?

Comment: That's the best I could add, I'm typing from an Android device

Comment: Just test it! for (int i=0;i<50000; i++){list.append("item " + i);} It might work, but may be unacceptable slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their is no limitation to number of items in a list. You can as well use stringItems appended to form, then add item commands to them... I hope this helps.
J2ME tutorial at http://www.tutorialmasterng.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations may have limit. Older Sony Ericsson phones have limit of 256 items in the list. Anyway, as Meier pointed out, lists with really many items can be slow or difficult to use. And 50k of strings may easily cause OOM on low heap devices (1 - 2 MB).